# Can we use a relative clause in this sentence "Tom received an email from the computer store that told him to post his computer to them"?

Tags: word-usage, phrase-usage, relative-clauses

Schools in Vietnam often focus on teaching students grammar, not common English expressions.

That is why Vietnamese students know a lot about relative clauses, reported speech, conditional sentences, etc but they can not express English sentences that sounds natural to native speakers' ears.

A Vietnamese student said this
"**Tom received an email from the computer store that told him to post his computer to them**"

I guess he tried to join 2 separated sentences using a relative pronoun

-Tom received an email from the computer store

-The store told him to post his computer to them

But I feel like it sounds unnatural to me

Can we use a relative clause in this sentence "**Tom received an email from the computer store that told him to post his computer to them**"?

Comment: Yes: it's a case of postposing of the relative clause. The salient interpretation is that the antecedent is "email" not "computer store". Note that there is no relative pronoun present; the relativised element is represented by a gap: "Tom received an email from the computer store that ___ told him to post his computer to them".

Comment: Your example is grammatical, but it would be more natural to say "Tom received an email from the computer store telling him to post his computer to them".

Comment: @BillJ, you should have a comma after "store" and "telling" modifies "an email" not "store". "Tom received an email from the computer store, telling him to post his computer to them"

Comment: A comma is optional. Of course the "telling" clause modifies "email". I never said otherwise.

Comment: This may be a dialect difference but using **post** as a verb here sounds odd to American English speakers.  We would usually say **mail** or **ship** his computer to them.

Comment: @BillJ What is "that" if not a relative pronoun?

Comment: @gotube It's a subordinator with the same function as the "that" found in declarative content clauses.

Comment: @BillJ In that sentence, "that" can be replaced with "which". Is "which" also a subordinator and not a relative pronoun?

Comment: @gotube No: "which is a relative pronoun, but "that" is not since it does not have the properties of a relative pronoun.

Comment: @BillJ Is "that" ever a relative pronoun?

Comment: @gotube No: in clause structure it's only ever a subordinator. In _that_ relatives a 'gap' is used to represent the position of subject or object, e.g. the relative clause in "The film that I wanted __ is not available" contains a gap in the position of object of "wanted", and this gap is related to the antecedent "film".

Answer (score 0):

The cited text is ambiguous. There's no way to conclusively decide whether the referent of ***that*** (which *could* have been ***which***) is the email or the computer store.

***But*** it would be possible (for *some* Anglophones, not all) to replace ***that*** with ***who***, in which case it could *only* refer to the computer store.